# How should I deal with "sph2pipe command not found" error message?

Tags: wav, sox

I'm trying to use the sph2pipe tool to convert the SPH files into wav or mp3 files. Although I have downloaded and installed the tool downloaded from here: https://www.ldc.upenn.edu/language-resources/tools/sphere-conversion-tools
still don't see any program that I can use..

1. On windows 10, after downloading sph2pipe and click the .exe file, a window just quickly popped up and never showed up again. And then I can't find any program called sph2pipe from the system and no command named sph2pipe either.
2. On Mac, I downloaded the program from where I forgot, but after clicked the executable file on mac, I got this document saying

> Last login: Tue May  8 18:57:21 on ttys001
>   Pennys-MBP:~ me$ /Users/me/Downloads/SPH/sph2pipe_v2.5/sph2pipe ; exit;
>   Usage: sph2pipe [-h hdr] [-t|-s b:e] [-c 1|2] [-p|-u|-a] [-f typ] infile [outfile]
>
> default conditions (for 'sph2pipe infile'):
>
> - input file contains sphere header
> - output full duration of input file
> - output all channels from input file
> - output same sample coding as input file
> - output format is WAV on Wintel machines, SPH elsewhere
> - output is written to stdout
>
> optional controls (items bracketed separately above can be combined):
>
> - -h hdr -- treat infile as headerless, get sphere info from file 'hdr'
> - -t b:e -- output portion between b and e sec (floating point)
> - -s b:e -- output portion between b and e samples (integer)
> - -c 1   -- only output first channel
> - -c 2   -- only output second channel
> - -p     -- force conversion to 16-bit linear pcm
> - -u     -- force conversion to 8-bit ulaw
> - -a     -- force conversion to 8-bit alaw
> - -f typ -- select alternate output header format 'typ'
>                  five types: sph, raw, au, rif(wav), aif(mac)
>
> logout
>
> Saving session...
>   ...copying shared history...
>   ...saving history...truncating history files...
>   ...completed.
>
> [Process completed]

But still when try to type sph2pipe on my terminal, I got the response:

> -bash: sph2pipe: command not found

Can somebody help me? I need to do the conversion very soon.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
sph2pipe.exe file file.wav
```